# Spring: <util:properties> ignored in JUnit environment?

Tags: spring, properties, junit

In my Spring servlet configuration (lets call it `service-servlet.xml`) I am loading properties from a file:

```
<util:properties id="ServiceProperties" location="classpath:service.properties" />
```

And then later autowiring them in my service class:

```
@Value("#{ServiceProperties['my.property']}")
private Integer myProp;
```

This works fine and service runs with no problems when deployed under Glassfish.

Now I am writing a test class for my service, and running it with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({
    "classpath:service-test-servlet.xml",
    "classpath:service-test-context.xml"
})
public class ServiceTest {
    // ...
}
```

So in `service-test-servlet.xml`, which is a copy of `service-servlet.xml` with few minor adjustments for testing environment, I do include the properties file the same way, but seems it is simply ignored...

First, I thought, I may be that my file is not found or so, but then even if I intentionally enter wrong name - it just ignores it and goes further with crashes at some later point because there is no bean named "ServiceProperties" and it cannot autowire "myProp" in my service class...

Is the `<util:properties>` being totally ignored in JUnit environment?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another service.properties in your test resources?

Comment: @mrembisz: doesn`'t matter how I name it, even if I try to include "WRONGservice.properties", it goes through it silently and does not even complain about non-existing file...

Comment: I have been using `PropertiesFactoryBean` in both production code and unit tests with no issues. Can you try that instead of `<util:properties>`?

Comment: @mrembisz appears it was misconfiguration in project causing a copy of configuration file being used instead of file changed, therefore it seemed as settings were ignored, while actually other file was used... By trying to use `PropertiesFactoryBean` I noticed the same behaviour like with `<util:properties>` what would be weird do be true - and then I found the issue; thanks for your time!